# Quickly Show These Two Numbers Are Equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials

> ***Question:*** I write 
>   $$\alpha={\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}\bigg(9 + i  \sqrt{687}\bigg)}\above 1.5
> pt 3^{2/3}} + {4 \above 1.5pt  {\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2} \bigg (9 + i
> \sqrt{687}\bigg)}}}$$ and
>
> $$\beta= {4\cos\left({1\above 1.5pt 3}\tan^{-1}\left({\sqrt{{229\above
> 1.5pt 3}}\above 1.5 pt 3}\right)\right)\above 1.5 pt \sqrt{3}}$$
>   How can we quickly show that $\alpha=\beta$ ?

Some background can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307203/is-this-sum-obviously-equal-to-8). The equality was established using WolfrmAlpha. I tried looking for some  trigonometric identities; which would quickly allow me to conclude the equality but I could not spot any. I do know that $687=3 \times 229$

Unrelated but worth mentioning is the following observation: I know that $\alpha$ is [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) since it is a root of the polynomial

$$(X^3-4X-1)(X^2-X-1)(X-1)$$

By equality we should have that $\beta$ is algebraic. But surprisingly if I  query WolframAlpha "Is $\beta$ algebraic" - WolframAlpha returns ***unknown***. Not sure what is going on there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-4x-1$ full stop. If you solve the cubic equation $x^3-4x-1=0$ through the [cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html) or through the triplication formula for the cosine function, you can easily check that the largest root of $x^3-4x-1$ can be written in both ways.

Comment: ^ this also explains why the roots are real.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: they clearly are by locating the stationary points of $x^3-4x-1$ or just by computing the discriminant of $x^3-4x-1$, i.e. $-7\cdot 2^{10}$.

Comment: D' Aurizio any idea why WolframAlpha is not showing that $\beta$ is algebraic ?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: some issue in dealing with inverse trigonometric functions, I guess. Anyway, $\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\arctan\gamma\right)$ is algebraic as soon as $\gamma$ is algebraic, always by the cosine triplication formulas.

Comment: And by the cosine triplication formula we mean:
$$
\cos(3\alpha)=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha
$$ ?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: exactly, yes.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of manipulations shows that

$${\sqrt3\alpha\over2}=\gamma+{1\over\gamma}\quad\text{with}\quad\gamma={\sqrt[3]{{3\over2}(9+i\sqrt{687})}\over2\sqrt3}$$

while

$${\sqrt3\beta\over2}=\delta+{1\over\delta}\quad\text{with}\quad\delta=e^{i\arctan(\sqrt{687}/9)/3}$$

Using the general identity $e^{i\arctan(y/x)}=(x+iy)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ when $x\gt0$, observe that

$$\delta^3=e^{i\arctan(\sqrt{687}/9)}={9+i\sqrt{687}\over\sqrt{81+687}}={9+i\sqrt{687}\over16\sqrt{3}}$$

while

$$\gamma^3={{3\over2}(9+i\sqrt{687})\over24\sqrt3}={9+i\sqrt{687}\over16\sqrt3}$$

It remains to note that

$$\gamma=\sqrt[3]{\gamma^3}=\sqrt[3]{\delta^3}=\delta$$

where "$\sqrt[3]{z}$" is understood as the principal branch for the cube root symbol.